# Job Market Signaling w/Continuous Ability

Tags: game-theory, labor-economics, signaling

I am currently trying to brush up on job signaling models for the upcoming semester, and came across this old exam question. There are no solutions to the question (that I am aware of), and I'm having trouble getting started with it. I have only done examples with binary ability, so I am not sure how to work with continuous ability. There are more parts to the question, but I think if I can understand these two that the rest will follow. Any help is greatly appreciated!

> Consider a labor market in which workers have heterogeneous ability, denoted $\theta$. Ability is uniformly distributed on the interval $\left[0,1\right]$. In the first period of the model workers choose a schooling level $e\in\left\{ 0,1\right\}$. The cost of schooling level $e$ for a worker of ability $\theta$ is $c\left(e,\theta\right)=\frac{\lambda e}{\theta}$ with $\lambda>0$. In a second period, a large number of firms compete a la Bertrand to hire workers. Firms observe schooling but not ability before making wages offers. Productivity in period 2 for a worker with ability $\theta$ and schooling $e$ is given by $y\left(\theta,e\right)=\theta\left(1+e\right)$. There is no discounting between periods.
>
> 1. Characterize a pooling PBE in which no workers obtain schooling. Under what conditions does such an equilibrium exist?
> 2. Now consider a separating equilibrium where some workers obtain schooling and others don't. Show that any separating equilibrium must involve a cutoff ability level $\bar{\theta}$, such that workers with ability above $\bar{\theta}$ obtain schooling and workers below $\bar{\theta}$ don't.

Comment: You can start by setting up IR and IC constraints for each type $\theta$, just like you would for the binary ability case.